# how to arrange the bullet list items in vertical

Tags: css, list

This is my [test_site](http://enteopinion.com/achievements/) .In there the list items are displaying not in order.
I know this is because of some silly css problem. but I don't know how to write the css to make them to display neatly. I tried

`display:inline,display:block` no use.

can anybody please help me to attain this?

Comment: Not specific to WP and probably better asked at [so].

Comment: i'm sorry. i was working in wordpress site so i thought i can ask about this in here. sorry my mistake.

Comment: No worries. :) Stack Overflow is better for more generic things, here we focus on aspects that are tightly tied to WordPress mechanics, rather than just happen in its context.

Comment: okay.. i got my answer.. sorry again.. i won't repeat this..again.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.entry-content li {
clear: both;
list-style-type:circle !important;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: it arranged correctly but the bullets where gone. can u just look into my site now because i have added ur code in css.

Comment: Hope the edits will work.

Answer (score 0):

try removing all style of the list.

then try this guide [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/12/11/styling-html-lists-with-css-techniques-and-resources)!